# Transformation of uniform distribution on finite set

Tags: probability

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ where $|M| < \infty$ and let $X$ be a random variable where

$$
P(X \in M) = 1
$$

and $\forall x \in M$

$$
P(X = x) = \frac{1}{|M|}
$$

i.e. $X$ is uniformly distributed on the finite set $M$. Let $t: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and define $Y=t(X)$.

What conditions are required on $t$ for $Y$ to be uniformly distributed on $t(M)$?

Comment: It must be bijective on $t(M)$, I guess.

Comment: $t$ would need to be bijective on $M$.

Comment: I was guessing the same but have no idea how to show it. Showing it is sufficient must be easy but showing it is necessary seems less obvious.

Comment: Actually, I am incorrect. For example, if $M=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $t(n) = n \mod 2$ then $t$ is uniformly distributed.